# Send different emails for last row / and additional rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to modify an existing macro by which I can perform the following functions:

1. Should have the option to enter the number of rows required to draft the email/s.
2. The Macro should include the last row plus the number of rows entered

(eg. I enter "5" that would mean Last row + 4 rows above it).

3. Individual email should be drafted for each row.

(eg. Last row would be Mailto = Colleague3@hotmail.com ; MailSubject = "EmailSubject_As_Per_the_Cell" Mailbody = "Hi Friend3, I’m inviting you for the conference being held today."

4. Other details are should be retained as is. (eg. Signatures etc.)

NOTE: My Excel sheet has 6-7 Columns which contains all the Project no./meeting no./Presenter Name/ Atendees name etc.

I tried tweaking with the VBA code but I'm not able to get through it.

```
Sub Mail_Outlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object, signature As String
    Dim irow As Integer

    Dim objItem As Object
    irow = InputBox("How many Invites do you want to send?")

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Cells(LastRow, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Mailto = Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(0, 5).Value
        If Mailto = "Colleague1" Then Mailto = "Colleague1@hotmail.com"
        If Mailto = " Colleague2" Then Mailto = " Colleague2@hotmail.com"
        If Mailto = " Colleague3" Then Mailto = " Colleague3@hotmail.com"  
    End If

    MailSubject = Cells(LastRow + irow, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value & " – Important Message"

    MailBody = "Hi " & Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(0, 5).Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    " I’m inviting you for the conference being held today." & _
    vbNewLine

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)

    With OutMail
         .Display
    End With

    signature = OutMail.body
    With OutMail
        .Subject = MailSubject
        .To = Mailto
        .body = MailBody & vbNewLine & signature
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presupposing you have the Outlook stuff handled correctly...  this looks like it's not actually sending any emails, just creating emails that are ready to be sent?

See if these changes bring you any closer to what you seek.  This code is lightly tested but are by no means bulletproof.

```
Sub Mail_Outlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object, signature As String
    Dim irow, i As Integer

    Dim objItem As Object
    irow = InputBox("How many Invites do you want to send?")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 0 To irow - 1

      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)

      If Cells(LastRow - i, 1).Value <> "" Then
          Mailto = Cells(LastRow - i, 5).Value
          If Mailto = "Colleague1" Or _
               Mailto = " Colleague2" Or _
               Mailto = " Colleague3" Then
             Mailto = Mailto & "@hotmail.com"
          End If
      End If

      MailSubject = Cells(LastRow - i, 4).Value & " – Important Message"
      MailBody = "Hi " & Cells(LastRow - i, 5).Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        " I’m inviting you for the conference being held today." & _
        vbNewLine

      With OutMail
        .Display
        signature = .body
        .Subject = MailSubject
        .To = Mailto
        .body = MailBody & vbNewLine & signature
      End With

    Next i

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Hambone,

Thanks for your reply. Yes, This is intended only to draft and keep mails ready to be sent. I tried running the code but the debugger gives me an error at:
'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)'
I'm not really a pro at VBA, just learning :)

Comment: "Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")" this change actually fixed the issue.

Comment: The code works fine for 2 or more emails but when I enter value as '1' it selects the second last row... can you please suggest what needs to be done to fix that?

Comment: Yeah, I only pasted the middle part of the code... everything above "LastRow" I didn't touch.  For clarity, I am replacing with the full code.  Also, I made a mistake -- I put `For i = 1 to irow` and it really should have been `0 to irow - 1` -- that's fixed as well.

Comment: THANKS A TON HAMBONE !...
WORKS PERFECTLY FINE AND AS INTENDED :)
CHEERS !

Comment: One extra thing !.. the signature appears as plain text. How to convert it to HTML?

Comment: There may be more to that than meets the eye since you are doing simple string concatenation for the body.  That said, if you use the `.HTMLBody` property of `OutMail` instead of `.body`, then it will render the body output as HTML